# Return value after task completed in URLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

what I want to do is when I send message to `-(void)downloadTaskStart`from another class then get the `bytesWritten` value (I use singleton), It'll return the value after the task finished(either with error or not), not the value at very first milisecond. Thanks to any help!

```
    @interface DownloadManager ()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *bytesWritten;

    @end

    @implementation DownloadManager

    - (void)downloadTaskStart {
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://somehost.com/somefile.zip];
        NSMutableURLRequest *downloadRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
                                                                   timeoutInterval:60];
        NSURLSessionConfiguration *config = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
        NSURLSession *downloadSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:config
                                                                      delegate:self
                                                                 delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];


        downloadTask = [downloadSession downloadTaskWithRequest:downloadRequest];
        startTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
        [downloadTask resume];

    }

    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error when download: %@", error);
        } 

        //do something?
    }

    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
        //do something?
    }

    - (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {            
        self.bytesWritten = [@(totalBytesWritten) stringValue];
    }

    @end
```

Comment: Maybe use [Delegates](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task didCompleteWithError:(NSError *)error
```

method of `NSURLSession` as it will be called when task is finished and in case of error and to pass the value use [Delegates](http://www.alexefish.com/post/522641eb31fa2a0015000002) or [NSNotification](http://nshipster.com/nsnotification-and-nsnotificationcenter/)